# Why is Clojure inconsistency about integer overflow?

Tags: clojure, integer-overflow

If I cast a big number to int directly, it complains there be an out of range error.

```
user=> (def x 4294967297)
user=> (int x)
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at user/eval1 (REPL:1).
Value out of range for int: 4294967297
```

However when I create an int array, it happily accepts that.

```
user=> (aget (int-array 1 x) 0)
1
```

Clojure 1.10.0

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/669a314861ac7f2cec55101def73e05852d4374d/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L1246 just uses `.intValue` and not the same impl as `(int ,,,)`

Comment: `int-array` uses `unchecked-int`, not `int`: `(= (unchecked-int 12345678901234567890) (first (int-array [12345678901234567890])))`.

Comment: Carelessness, I think.